# How to perform Search functionality in flutter with rest api and Search Delegate?

Tags: django, flutter, django-rest-framework, flutter-layout

I am trying to achieve a search view like what we have on youtube.  With search delegate in flutter, I could only achieve a search with hardcoded data.  But I could not do the same with the Rest API.  I have created a Rest API with Django rest framework.

Django rest Framework Search API:

```
    class SearchApi(generics.ListAPIView):
        queryset = Youtube.objects.all()
        serializer_class = YoutubeSerializer
        filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
        search_fields = ['title', 'description']
```

Search Delegate in Flutter

```
    class DataSearch  extends SearchDelegate<String> {
    
      final cities = [
        'Chennai',
        'Mumbai',
        'Jaipur',
        'Visa',
        'America',
        'Japan',
        'North India',
        'Tamil Nadu'
      ];
    
      final recentCities = [
        'America',
        'Japan',
        'North India',
        'Tamil Nadu'
      ];
    
      @override
      List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
        // TODO: implement buildActions
        return [IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.clear),onPressed: (){
          query = '';
        },)];
        throw UnimplementedError();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
        // TODO: implement buildLeading
        return IconButton(
          icon: AnimatedIcon(
            icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow,
            progress: transitionAnimation,
          ),
          onPressed: (){
            close(context, null);
          },
        );
        throw UnimplementedError();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
        // TODO: implement buildResults
        print(query);
        List<Youtube> list = List();
        List<dynamic> youtubeList = List();
        var isLoading = false;
    
        return Column(
          children: [
            Text('Hello')
          ],
        );
        throw UnimplementedError();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
        // TODO: implement buildSuggestions
        return Column(
          children: [
            Text('Hello')
          ],
        );
        throw UnimplementedError();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the code of buildResult with the rest API? Do you use a Future builder or StreamBuilder to fetch the data?

Comment: I am using Future Builder.

Comment: Any answers to this?? I also need to use search and then display data based on search query from API